# Can't edit/delete some events on my iPad's calendar

Tags: ipad, ios, calendar

I've had a problem since upgrading my iPad to IOS 5 in that I can't seem to edit/delete some events on my calendar. It mainly seems to be repeating events that have the problem. Any ideas about what may be causing this?

Comment: How are you getting the calendar data? is it from a third party like Google Calendars? or is it synced with iCloud?

Comment: Are you syncing with your computer?

Comment: Most of the events are entered on my iPad. I also synch the device with my calendar in MS Exchange. I don't use Google calendars. The device is synched to my PC about once a week.

Comment: seems you may be syncing twice, try the answer I posted here, it should apply for the iPad aswell. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31184/how-to-remove-extra-iphone-calendars/31185#31185

Comment: I checked those settings iTunes, and it's actually not currently configured to sync with Outlook. Contacts, Calendars are all unchecked. So it must only be syncing via iCloud.

Comment: So is your device syncing with MS Exchange through a server or a PC? Did you create these events or are they from a downloaded calendar.

Comment: It's syncing from a server and all the events were either created on the iPad itself or my iPhone.

Comment: I have no problem editing events on the iPhone.

Comment: That is very strange, i'm not really sure what has happened, I would not sync with the PC at all, but just rely on iCloud, have you checked your www.iCloud.com account to see if the events are editable/duplicated or have any errors in fact. Also check your icloud settings and make sure in (Mail-Contacts-Calendars) you only have one calendar synced, and make that one you iCloud one.

Comment: I can edit/delete the same events in iCloud without any issues. I have changed the settings to sync with the iCloud calendar only.

Comment: let me know if that worked, ill add it as the answer. If not, then I cant help.

Comment: That workaround has been a success. I have now ditched the MS Exchange calendar, and I'm only using the iCloud calendar, which is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked your www.iCloud.com account to see if the events are editable/duplicated or have any errors in fact. Also check your icloud settings and make sure in (Mail-Contacts-Calendars) you only have one calendar synced, and make that one you iCloud one.

Comment: I can edit the events on iCloud and they don't have any errors. Currently I am only synching the iCloud cal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I upgraded from Snow Leopard to Lion and lost my Quicken (didn't upgrade Quicken before going to Lion)... and with it all my info attached in my calendar. Any calendar events "attached" to Quicken in my calendar on my ipad can not be edited or deleted now. This was all originally created on my Mac.

### The Fix:

What I did to correct this was, on my iPad, in iCal, touch the "Calendars" button in the top left corner.  In "From my Mac" I unchecked the Quicken Data calendar.  All the events disappeared.  I created a new calendar and recreated the events I wanted.  Everything works as expected for me now!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this if you use a mac, delete event from your iCal then sync iPhone in itunes and go to info, calendar, sync whatever you save as, i.e, home, work, etc then push sync. If you deleted event from your iCal once you sync the event goes away

Answer (score 0):

I had an event in my iPad but it didn't appear on the iPhone or the Mac.

There was no delete or decline option, but as soon as I changed the calendar it was sitting in, Decline showed up and I was able to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem also, Here is what I did, Hope it helps someone.
I had made Calendar events on my iMac which ranged over a week or more, and I was unable to edit these on my iPad.
I noticed that if the event was only 1 day I had no problem editing on the iPad , and also that I could edit all events even the longer ones from my iPhone or from iCloud.
What is needed on the iPad is to change from month view to day view and then I can edit the long events just fine.